# How to show subscript and upperscript at the same time?

Tags: html

I want to show that formula:

[image]

How ever generally I saw that poeople use something like that but it does not fill the bill:

θ<sup>(T-20)</sup><sub>FPOP</sub>

Comment: What about using a table to format it like that?

Comment: What you mean sorry?

Comment: You could use a html table to show that like you want. I created it for you here: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vaGzKj) From there you could style it with CSS the way you want it to be displayed.

Comment: I did not know that usage, appreciate!

Comment: posted it as an anwser as well, I'd like to see it as an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a table and style it accordingly. 
I made an example right [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vaGzKj).

This is how it will look in html. You give the "0" a rowspan, so it will be the size of two tablerows. Then you just add your superscripted/subscripted in single rows and voilá.

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="row2">0</td>
      <td class="small">(T-20)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="small">FPON</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to show that in pyqt QLabel. Howevet it shows like that: https://imgur.com/a/5yoLm43

Comment: Well I don't know anything about pyQT. You just tagged HTML so I went for that solution. Maybe try the CSS-Solution from the answer below? 
Tell us afterwards, how you solved that.

Answer (score 1):

Using position in css works well.

```css
.sup-sub {
  position: relative;
}
.sup-sub > sub:nth-child(2),
.sup-sub > sup:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.sup-sub > sub:nth-child(2) {
  bottom: -0.5em;
}
.sup-sub > sup:nth-child(2) {
  top: -0.5em;
}
```

```html
<p>
  OOO
  <span class = 'sup-sub'>
    <sub>222</sub>
    <sup>2222</sup>
  </span>
</p>

<p>
  OOO
  <span class = 'sup-sub'>
    <sup>2</sup>
    <sub>222</sub>
  </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more example (based on **[MathJax](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax)**):

```js
window.MathJax = {
  config: ["MMLorHTML.js"],
  jax: ["input/TeX", "input/MathML", "input/AsciiMath", "output/HTML-CSS", "output/NativeMML"],
  extensions: ["tex2jax.js", "mml2jax.js", "asciimath2jax.js", "MathMenu.js", "MathZoom.js"],
  asciimath2jax: {
    delimiters: [
      ['`', '`'],
      ['$', '$']
    ]
  },
  TeX: {
    extensions: ["AMSmath.js", "AMSsymbols.js", "noErrors.js", "noUndefined.js"]
  },
  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [
      ['$', '$'],
      ["\\(", "\\)"]
    ],
    processEscapes: true
  }
};
```

```css
.MathJax_CHTML {
  font-size: 30px !important;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
<h1> MathJax virtually aligned superscript and subscript </h1>
<p>
  $\theta^{(T-20)}_{FPON}$
</p>
```